# Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "27-08-2020" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Tags: angular, angular8

I need to format a date in an angular application so I use the Date Pipe:  I am trying so many custom filter.

I used:

```
<div class="id_text">{{ splitDate(row?.created_at) | date:'dd-MM-y'}}</div>
 splitDate(date) {
const data = date.split(' ');
return data[0];
}
```

I Used Angular Filter

```
<div class="id_text">{{row?.created_at | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</div>
```

But still getting same error somewhere date does not display I need only date

[image]

[image]

Response:-

[image]

Comment: It seems created_at property have invalid date string. check this:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Invalid_date

Comment: how can I correct? I am trying many custom filter still getting the same error. @Chellappanவ

Comment: If the response is returned by backend, you need to return valid date string from back end before convert it to desired format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `created_at` has invalid date string and angular pipe not recognizing it.

All you need to replace this `25-09-2020 11:04:16` with this `2020/2/25 11:04:16`, you can do it by writing a date parser method.

```
  parseDate(date) {
   const parseDate = date.split('-');
   const parseTime = parseDate[2].split(' ');
   const parsedDate = `${parseTime[0]}/${parseDate[1]}/${parseDate[0]} ${parseTime[1]}`

   return parsedDate
 }
```

Use date parse in template

```
<div class="id_text">{{ parseDate(row?.created_at) | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</div>
```

Comment: thanks! @Kamran its working.. I need one more issue if you have 2min can we connect https://meet.google.com/vuo-dbxs-gzs

Comment: @Abid what is it about you can briefly explain here.

Comment: actually, I have multiple statuses so I want to show dynamically active one by one i am not able to write the code here

Comment: I guess thats not related to this question you could post a new question with details, I will try to address it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64099707/how-to-make-angular-material-stepper-active-dynamically-when-status-will-come-on

please check here

Comment: @Abid okay I am checking, if this answer address your question feel free to accept and upvote it would help other colleagues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222171/discussion-between-kamran-khatti-and-abid).